# How to call PL/SQL fucntion with REF_CURSOR using JPA or JDBC

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, jdbc

I have created function in PL/SQL that returns names of all tables in my schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbINFO
return sys_refcursor AS 
table_info sys_refcursor;
begin
    open table_info
        for select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'HOMEUSER';

        return table_info;
end;
```

I want to call it using JDBC or if it is possible JPA.

How can I do it? I tried almost everything with no result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997729/how-to-execute-a-procedure-with-jdbc

Comment: @YCF_L unfortunetly it is not answering my question. I have a function not procedure. I want to return information using ref_cursor and print it while my program starts.

Comment: did you learn https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-call-an-existing-function-in-a-database-using-jdbc-api

Comment: [How does this differ from your earlier question on the same subject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796051/how-to-use-jpa-or-jdbc-to-call-specific-pl-sql-function-using-ref-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

create named native query on any of your entity class.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="getAllTablesOwnedByHomeUser",
callable=true , query = "{? = call dbINFO()}",
resultClass = Pojo.class) //Pojo is class whch u r using 2 map resltset.


 //Field name in Pojo class and Table columns name should match which are returned 
   // by the cursor
```

Now call the named query using your EntityManager as below.

```
  EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
TypedQuery<Pojo.class> q = em.createNativeQuery("getAllTablesOwnedByHomeUser",Pojo.class);
List<Pojo> tables = q.getResultList();
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```